# Connecting iOS application to Web Service (Swift)

Tags: php, ios

I am having trouble understanding how to connect my iOS application to a web service. I already have a .php file connecting to the database and outputting the correct results. Also, I have the link that I am suppose to connecting to, but I just don't understand how the two connect. (I am creating a login page)

Answer (score 0):

Try to read about JSON Parsing and create your own web services.